# What is causing a Swift UserDefault to not be set until the 2nd try?

Tags: swift, swiftui, userdefaults, appstorage

I am trying to let the user control settings for camera hardware so there is a Settings view and a different view where they can choose presets to apply by the click of a button. When navigating back to the Settings view (via a TabView), I expect the values to be shown according to whichever preset button was clicked. However, I am finding that the *some* of the UserDefault-stored values are not being changed unless the button was clicked twice.

Differences between the correctly updated UserDefaults and the non-working ones:
-The non-working (until 2nd click) values are presented (and able to be changed) in the Settings view in a TextField whereas the correctly working values are presented (and able to be changed) by a Slider.
-The non-working values are Ints by default and updated to be Ints, while the others are Floats.

Things I have tried:
`UserDefaults.standard.setValue(values[0], forKey: "exposureISO")`
`UserDefaults.standard.set(Int(values[0], forKey: "exposureISO")`
`UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()`

Here is my code that hopefully demonstrates where the issue might be:\

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Settings: View {

    let minISO = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "minISO")
    let maxISO = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "maxISO")
    let maxGain = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "maxGain")

    @AppStorage("exposureISO") var exposureISO = DefaultSettings.exposureISO
    @State private var enteredExposureISO: String = ""
    @AppStorage("redGain") var redGain = DefaultSettings.redGain

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                TextField("", text: self.$enteredExposureISO)
                    .onReceive(Just(enteredExposureISO)) { typedValue in
                        if let newValue = Int(typedValue) {
                            if (newValue >= Int(minISO)) && (newValue <= Int(maxISO)) {
                                exposureISO = newValue
                            }
                        }
                    }
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .padding()
                .onAppear(perform:{self.enteredExposureISO = "\(exposureISO)"})

                Slider(
                    value: $redGain,
                    in: 1...Double(maxGain),
                    step: 0.1
                ) {
                    Text("red Gain")
                } minimumValueLabel: {
                    Text("1")
                } maximumValueLabel: {
                    Text("4")
                }
                .padding([.leading, .trailing, .bottom])
            }
        }
    }
}

enum DefaultSettings {
    static let exposureISO = 300
    static let redGain = 2.0
}

struct JobView: View {

    @ObservedObject var job: Job //does this need to be observed...?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Settings").fontWeight(.medium)
            Text(job.settings ?? "settings not found")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        
            Button(action: applySettings) {
                Text("Apply these settings")
            }
        }
    }

    func applySettings() {
    //parse job.settings and apply the values to the camera hardware
        var value = ""
        var values : [Float] = []
        for char in job.settings! {
            if Int(String(char)) != nil || char == "." {
                value.append(char)
            } else if char == "\n" {
                values.append(Float(value)!)
                value = ""
            }
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(values[0], forKey: "exposureISO")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(values[1], forKey: "redGain")
    }
}
```

I find it most strange that the UserDefaults are being properly set if the button is tapped twice. I appreciate any help diagnosing the issue and how to solve it!

## Edit

Like described in comments and as ChrisR suggested, I changed `.onReceive` to `.onSubmit` to hack/solve the problem, but I don't yet entirely understand why the `Just(...)` publisher was emitting when the button was tapped. Here's the fix:\

```
TextField("", text: self.$enteredExposureISO)
    .onSubmit {
        if let newValue = Int(enteredExposureISO) {
            if (newValue >= Int(minISO)) && (newValue <= Int(maxISO)) {
                print("new value \(newValue)")
                exposureISO = newValue
            }
        }
    }
    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    .padding()
    .onAppear(perform:{self.enteredExposureISO = "\(exposureISO)"})
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `UserDefaults.standard`... and `@AppStorage`? If you just use @AppStorage you can set and read the vars like any other var and they get saved to UserDefaults automatically.

Comment: I suppose that I'm using `UserDefaults.standard`... instead of `@AppStorage` for when I'm only reading or writing to keys but not otherwise having the corresponding variables be dynamically updated. By the way, I've found the problem lies in the `.onRecieve()` block being called immediately when the button is tapped so the variable (exposureISO in this case) is getting changed back to the value in the TextField... I'm working on how to resolve this and will update the post once I've realized it.

Comment: I just found that it could also be related to setting the `enteredExposureISO`at `.onAppear` ... Do you use a TabView? Because this can create problems in combination with .onAppear

Comment: ...as for `.onReceive`– you can also use `.onSubmit`